# How to make CSS Grid stay set size regardless of entries?

Tags: html, css, jsp, grid

I have a CSS Grid that slowly fills up with entries over time using JSP. The grid itself has a background color and the entries have their own color inside the grid. The issue is that the grid grows in size as entries are added. I want the grid background to remain a set size and have the entries pop up inside it as they are added (I have a max entry limit set on my server side, so don't worry about that).

Is this possible? I have included some pictures below:

**No Chore Entries Added:**
[image]

**3 Chore Entries Added:**
[image]

Unlike the pictures above ^^ I want my dashboard grid to be fixed to a certain size always and just have these entries show up inside filling it up overtime.

HTML

```
    <div class="chore-container">
        <c:forEach var="chore" items="${data}">
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.chore-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 250px 0 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.chore {
  background-color: #c2c0c0;
  border: 1px solid #c2c0c0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Outfit, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `max-height` and `overflow-y` properties to your `.chore-container`.

`max-height: 200px` will make it so your container will remain at a fixed height.

`overflow-y: scroll` will allow a scrollbar to appear on the y-axis to scroll through the contents of the container.

```css
.chore-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 250px 0 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chore {
  background-color: #c2c0c0;
  border: 1px solid #c2c0c0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Outfit, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chore-container">
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
            <div class="chore">${chore.name}, ${chore.points} Points</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution...mostly flexbox and a bit of position absolute, otherwise you end up with double scrollbars.

```css
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;

    }

    .top {

      color: #fff;
      background: #40B6C0;
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 25px;
   
    }

    .scroll-region {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: white;
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      flex-direction: column;

    }

    .chore {
      background-color: #c2c0c0;
      border: 1px solid #c2c0c0;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: Outfit, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .add-chore {
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #cc0000;
      color: white;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 3px 6px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-content: flex-end;
      align-self: flex-end;
    

    }

    .chore-container {

      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 50px;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
      background-color: #ebebeb;
      padding: 10px;
      /* margin: 0 250px 0 250px; */
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 3px;
      width: 80%;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />




</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="top">
   <a href="" class="add-chore">ADD CHORE</a>
  </div>

    <div class="scroll-region">

      <div class="chore-container">

        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
        <div class="chore">SWEEP, 10 Points</div>
    
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```